# Unable to publish to azure after azure and project version upgrade

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I have upgraded my windows azure project from VS2010 to VS2013. I updated all assemblies by package manager using update-package command and downloaded latest configuration file from azure portal. But when I try to publish the site it always shows error   `A security token validation error occurred for the received JWT token.  Http Status Code: Unauthorized  OperationId:` Has any one have any idea how to get rid of this error and publish successfully?

Comment: How long does your publish step take?  If uploading your CSPKG takes a long time (I forget the exact time, but I think 30 minutes) due to slow network or large CSPKG size then the authentication token will expire and Visual Studio won't be able to create the deployment.

Comment: This takes really long time to publish. It is happening with old version of project but I was able to publish with this delay. Is this a problem with new SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With older SDKs the only authentication mechanism was Service Management certificates.  With newer SDKs we added the active directory authentication option.  With AD authentication Visual Studio will acquire an auth token at the beginning of publishing and then continue to use that token for the duration of the publishing.  If the upload of the CSPKG takes a long time due to slow network conditions or large package size then the auth token will expire and Visual Studio will throw the Unauthorized error when it tries to perform the next publishing operation after the CSPKG upload.

To resolve this you can do a few things:

1. Use a certificate for authentication.  You can manage this by configuring your Azure account in VS and switching to the certificates tab.
2. Build the CSPKG in Visual Studio, upload it to storage, then publish from the portal or Powershell and point to the CSPKG in storage.

A future SDK will automatically renew this token so that you don't have to worry about this authentication issue, but I don't know which SDK this will be included in.